# How to pick phone ringtones using phonegap?

Tags: cordova

Hi I am new to phone gap technology
I am trying to select ringtones stored internally in Phone.
But i do not know How to use it?

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just created a plugin which opens phone's ringtone selection window.

**plugin**

https://github.com/vasani-arpit/cordova-plugin-RingtoneSelector

**Sample Project**

https://github.com/vasani-arpit/RingtoneSelectorSample

basic syntax is following

```
    var success = function (uriPath) {
        //do whatever you want with URI path of selected ringtone
    }

    var failure = function () {
        alert("Error calling Plugin");
    }

    cordova.plugins.RingtoneSelector.open("This is plugin.", success, failure);
```